# How to manage visible layers sets in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Say I have to create two, or more versions of one web page in Photoshop. That means, generally layout and all the design stays the same, but in one version there is one layer visible, and in another version the other layer is visible instead. I create two layers with different content for two versions and switch between them. What I am looking for is some plugin, or advise how to manage layers sets better.

This plugin would let me add layers to some groups - Version 1, Version 2. Then I would click Version 1 group and only layers from that group become visible. Then I click Group 2, and it would do the same for that group layers. Now I have to manually find respective layers and toggle their visibility.

Is there some solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already supported in Photoshop and it's called Layer Compositions. You can toggle between visibility, position and other attributes on layers which means that you can make quite complicated changes without having to duplicate layers per site version you make.

You have a lot of good information [on the official layer comps page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7870a.html).

Maybe [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25ZCThU9UkE) is more helpful.